# Unknown chrome notification from shoutmeloud.pushengage.com on my Mac

Tags: virus, chrome, macos

On my Mac, I recently started to see popup of a notification while using chrome. The notifications are from a website called `shoutmeloud.pushengage.com`.
I ran an anti-virus scan but it didn’t detect anything.

I tried to disable some chrome extensions but this did not remove the issue.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

PushEngage seems to be an HTML5 push notification provider. It would allow a site to easily embed push notifications (including desktop notifications if the browser supports it). It does not look malicious in itself.

Of course, it may be abused by a site to deliver spammy notifications to you, provided you have their site open in a tab somwhere (or a browser extension). Check your frequently used tabs and installed extensions. Sometimes a site can be exploited to include malicious code that could generate such notifications, similar to malvertising.

Answer (score 2):

ShoutMeLoud is a blog. They use PushEngage to send out push notifications to you on your desktop. You likely visited the site, subscribed to their push notification system, and then forgot.

Nothing malicious here.

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) does not even require a tab with that website open. The browser will remember the registration and accept the notification and run the custom code in the background.

I think this is a completely over-engineered and unnecessary feature and people should disable it in their browser's options.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the site permissions to send notifications to you from here 
chrome://settings/contentExceptions#notifications.
At one or other point of time you might had given the permission for website to send the notifications to you ,Its not any virus or anything.Without your consent/permission chrome doesn't allow this to happen,its just that you might had forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

i am quite familiar with  Pushengage.It is a web push notification service provider.
Push notification Can not be a virus effect, here is why?
Push notification involves Service Workers.A service worker can only be registered if From a provider if you allow notifications from that provider.
Shoutmeloud Started using Desktop Push notifications from previous last year.I am sure That you have subscribed to their push notifications.This is why you are getting notifications from them.
Here is how to unsubscribe from their Push notifications

1. visit https://shoutmeloud.pushengage.com/?action=subscribe  and
   click on Green Secure lock icon
2. Set notifications to block or ask.

now press ctrl+shift+i 
and move to application tab and unregister it

Now you are Unsubscribed to push notifications from shoutmeloud.

Now they never force you to see their notifications.

Comment: Browser-based push notifications in general are benign and your suggested sequence definitely works. 

Is it possible that some other software tricked the user into "subscribing" to the notifications? Especially since a user would've remembered it if they had clicked yes, to "Enable notifications for this site"?